# How to get the value of "Name" from first row of table every time when table content changes based on dropdown?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to get the value of "Name" from first row of table when table content changes based on dropdownlist. Currently, this is working when the page first loads. But I want the `name` value when dropdownlist changes.

Controller

```
public ActionResult ABC()
{
    SDetails sDetails=new SDetails();        
    var model = new ClsA();          
    string name = sDetails.Rst().FirstOrDefault().Name;    
    model.firsts = sDetails.Rst();                    
    model.seconds = sDetails.Rs(name);            
    return View(model);
}
```

View

```
@model Aplication.Models.ABC.ClsA 

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.drpList, new List<SelectListItem>
{                       
    new SelectListItem {Value = "ls", Text="Laa" },
    new SelectListItem {Value = "ms", Text = "Maa"},    
},new { @id = "CountryList"})

<div id=myA>
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_PartialA", Model.firsts); }
</div>
<div id=myB>
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_PartialB", Model.seconds);} 
</div>
```

_PartialA

```
@model IEnumerable<Aplication.Models.ABC.first>
table>
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Name)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Address)</th>            
    </tr>    
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)</td>                
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

_PartialB

```
@model  IEnumerable<Aplication.Models.ABC.second>
<table>
    <tr>
       <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Details)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Age)</th>            
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Details)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Age)</td>                
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Have you heard of AJAX???  Google cascading dropdown list.

Comment: @Eric, Yes I have heard about AJAX. But I want to get the 1st row `name` value from the table when the dropdownlist changes.

Comment: The Name from which table (both tables contain `Name` properties)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, the name from `first` table. As you suggested, On page load I am getting the `name` value. But I want the same when the dropdown list changes.

Comment: Not really clear what the point of that is (it will always be the same value so you could have passed it to the view - but `$('#CountryList').change(function() { var name = $('#myA').find('table').find('tr').eq(1).find('td').first().text(); });`

Comment: @StephenMuecke this is what I am looking for. I will try and see. Please give me sometime. Thank you.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, It works for me. Thank you. Please provide an answer. I will accept it.

Comment: I don't understand what the point of this is. When you select the "Laa" option you get the value. The if you select "Maa", you run the code again to get exactly the same value (its a bit pointless and a waste of resources)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, No Stephen. The `name` value will be changing everytime when we select value from dropdown.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170679/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-user9895).

Comment: @StephenMuecke, i found the solution based on your code.